# Javascript array to viewmodel string array

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-viewmodel

Trying to pick up an array created in javascript when posted back to the controller action as a string array on a ViewModel but it's not working...

```
var action = '/Controller/Action';
var array = ['item1', 'item2', ...]; 
var data = { ArrayName: array };

$.post(action, data, function (result) {
         ...
}



public class ArrayViewModel
{
   public string[] ArrayName{ get; set; }
}

public ActionResult Action(ArrayViewModel arrayViewModel)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Which framework/library?

Comment: What's the name of your controller?  Can you set a breakpoint and see if the if the controller action is being invoked?  Does the data post as null, or does an error occur on POST?

Comment: The array is the problem, if I use a string instead of a string array it works fine.

Comment: Yes it's null when I breakpoint. And if I switch it to a string it gets passed through ok.